# howto use activeresource on rails 1.2.3 (cc.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I'm working on a cc.rb plugin and need activeresource support. as cc.rb runs on rails 1.2.3, there is no activeresource support. is there a way to use activeresource on rails 1.2.3, since i don't want to upgrade cc.rb to rails 2.3.2?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe work with them on the upgrade path to Rails 3?